# Why my service restarted every 90 seconds?

Tags: ubuntu, service, systemd, systemctl

I'm working with Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Here's the `.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=NoDescpt

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/git/cmd/daphnei
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And the related script `/home/git/cmd/daphnei`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/git/hsfzmun/server
/home/git/virtualenvs/hsfzmun/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 -v2 config.asgi:channel_layer
```

What confused me is that the service will restart every 90 seconds, but I can't find out why.

---

I've found that the service's status is always `activating`, which means `systemd` doesn't know that the service has been started. However the script **did** start because I can visit my website. So what's wrong with it?

Comment: Check logs files

Comment: @FedericoSierra Logs are fine, no errors. Actually I have several services with the same issues. Does 90 seconds a special value for systemd?

Comment: Check the _right_ log files with the _right_ verbosity settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using

```
Type=Notify
```

in your unit file. It means that the application should notify systemd when it is ready to server via [sd-notify](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_notify.html#)  Systemd probably receives no notification from your app and restarts it.

Unless your application is sending notification to systemd, you should update corresponding line to

```
Type=simple
```

Other option is to check whether `daphne` can send notification to systemd and turn the notification on.

Check [systemd documentation on notify](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Options) for more details on `Type=notify`

Answer (score 5):

Since it hasn't stated that it is ready within 90 seconds (the default start timeout), systemd has decided that your service has failed. Failed services get everything killed off.

Becuase of `Restart=always`, your failed service is then restarted, and the cycle repeats.

Also, `Restart=on-failure` might be better in this case.

Comment: Thanks! But I still have a question: why systemd doesn't think my service has started even if my script worked well and didn't make any errors?

Comment: I am not sure about my knowledge in scripts but adding this might help `User=root` and `Type=""` Also, adding `WorkingDirectory=/home/root` will set script to directory.

Comment: @hsfzxjy Why would you have `Restart=always` in the first place if your script isn't supposed to run continuely?

Comment: @Anubioz actually the script starts a server but it was shutdowned and restarted cyclely. Now I've know the reason.